# How can I display a simple animated spectrogram to visualize audio from a MixerHostAudio object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working off of some of Apple's sample code for mixing audio (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html) and I'd like to display an animated spectrogram (think itunes spectrogram in the top center that replaces the song title with moving bars). It would need to somehow get data from the audio stream live since the user will be mixing several loops together. I can't seem to find any tutorials online about anything to do with this.

Comment: Spectrogram/spectograph, not equalizer.

Comment: Thanks, I just corrected it. That's probably why I couldn't find anything online about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's aurioTouch example app (on developer.apple.com) has source code for drawing an animated frequency spectrum plot from recorded audio input.  You could probably group FFT bins into frequency ranges for a coarser bar graph plot.

Answer (score 4):

I know I am really late for this question. But I just found some great resource to solve this question.

Solution:

1. Instantiate an audio unit to record samples from the microphone of the iOS device.
2. Perform FFT computations with the vDSP functions in Apple’s Accelerate framework.
3. Draw your results to the screen using a UIImage

Computing the FFT or spectrogram of an audio signal is a fundamental audio signal processing. As an iOS developer, whether you want to simply find the pitch of a sound, create a nice visualisation, or do some front end processing it’s something you’ve likely thought about if you are at all interested in audio. Apple does provide a sample application for illustrating this task (aurioTouch). The audio processing part of that App is obscured, however, imho, by extensive use of Open GL.

The goal of this project was to abstract as much of the audio dsp out of the sample app as possible and to render a visualisation using only the UIKit. The resulting application running in the iOS 6.1 simulator is shown to the left. There are three components. rscodepurple1 A simple ‘exit’ button at the top, a gain slider at the bottom (allowing the user to adjust the scaling between the magnitude spectrum and the brightness of the colour displayed), and a UIImageView displaying power spectrum data in the middle that refreshes every three seconds. Note that the frequencies run from low to the high beginning at the top of the image. So, the top of the display is actually DC while the bottom is the Nyquist rate. The image shows the results of processing some speech.

This particular Spectrogram App records audio samples at a rate of 11,025 Hz in frames that are 256 points long. That’s about 0.0232 seconds per frame. The frames are windowed using a 256 point Hanning window and overlap by 1/2 of a frame.

Let’s examine some of the relevant parts of the code that may cause confusion. If you want to try to build this project yourself you can find the source files in the archive below.

First of all look at the content of the PerformThru method. This is a callback for an audio unit. Here, it’s where we read the audio samples from a buffer into one of the arrays we have declared.

```
SInt8 *data_ptr = (SInt8 *)(ioData->mBuffers[0].mData);
for (i=0; i<inNumberFrames; i++) {

     framea[readlas1] = data_ptr[2];

     readlas1 += 1;

     if (readlas1 >=33075) {
       readlas1 = 0;

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [THIS printframemethod];
       });
     }

data_ptr += 4;

}
```

Note that framea is a static array of length 33075. The variable readlas1 keeps track of how many samples have been read. When the counter hits 33075 (3 seconds at this sampling frequency) a call to another method printframemethod is triggered and the process restarts.

The spectrogram is calculated in printframemethod.

```
for (int b = 0; b < 33075; b++) {
  originalReal[b]=((float)framea[b]) * (1.0 ); //+ (1.0 * hanningwindow[b]));
}

for (int mm = 0; mm < 250; mm++) {

for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++) {
  tempReal[b]=((float)framea[b + (128 * mm)]) * (0.0 + 1.0 * hanningwindow[b]);
}



vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX *) tempReal, 2, &A, 1, nOver2);
vDSP_fft_zrip(setupReal, &A, stride, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);

scale = (float) 1. / 128.;

vDSP_vsmul(A.realp, 1, &scale, A.realp, 1, nOver2);
vDSP_vsmul(A.imagp, 1, &scale, A.imagp, 1, nOver2);

for (int b = 0; b < nOver2; b++) {
  B.realp[b] = (32.0 * sqrtf((A.realp[b] * A.realp[b]) + (A.imagp[b] * A.imagp[b])));
}

for (int k = 0; k < 127; k++) {
  Bspecgram[mm][k]=gainSlider.value * logf(B.realp[k]);
  if (Bspecgram[mm][k]<0) {
    Bspecgram[mm][k]=0.0;
  }
}

}
```

Note that in this method we first cast the signed integer samples to floats and store in the array originalReal. Then the FFT of each frame is computed by calling the vDSP functions. The two-dimensional array Bspecgram contains the actual magnitude values of the Short Time Fourier Transform. Look at the code to see how these magnitude values are converted to RGB pixel data.

Things to note:

To get this to build just start a new single-view project and replace the delegate and view controller and add the aurio_helper files. You need to link the Accelerate, AudioToolbox, UIKit, Foundation, and CoreGraphics frameworks to build this. Also, you need PublicUtility. On my system, it is located at /Developer/Extras/CoreAudio/PublicUtility. Where you find it, add that directory to your header search paths.

Get the code:

The delegate, view controller, and helper files are included in this zip archive.

[A Spectrogram App for iOS in purple](http://prog.roaringshark.com/?p=5)

Comment: Any chance you could upload to Github? The link is broken.

Comment: I think the owner has withdrawn that project. Sorry. It was over one year. @Youngin